# Why eclipse dont find projects in import volley (android) directory from git?

Tags: android, eclipse, git, import, android-volley

I have a problem, please tell me what this trouble.
I need volley library, i made this steps for import:
 1. Click import
 2. Select Git => Projects from git => url
 3. Paste https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley to URL => Click next
 4. Select master brunch => click next
 5. Select directory => click next
 6. In Import project: "No project found"

I tried import project from Existing local repository and from Existing Android Code Into Workspace, eclipse all the same dont see this project.....
Thanks for watching and answer!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The git repository does not contain any .project file, which basically makes up an Eclipse project. That's the reason why you don't see any projects when selecting 'Import existing projects'.

Comment: This is, perhaps, the most useless correct answer ever.

Answer (score 1):

on step 6 select "import as general project"

if it still shows no project found, then i recommend the .jar file here 
http://api.androidhive.info/volley/volley.jar

Answer (score 0):

You can 'import from existing code' and then copy the java folder content to the src folder.